# Jquery top panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hey guys** 
I have a question which is... I want a panel at the top of my website that stays at the top of the web browsers view. like here

http://webeffectual.com/

In this website the top panel stays at the top even though  you scroll through the website

**My question** is can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this or tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what they used on the site you referenced.

Specifically, they are using `'position:fixed;` to keep it in place and `z-index: 20;` to keep it on top.

```
#header {
  background: url("../images/header.png") repeat-x scroll 0 top transparent;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 116px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: My pleasure, @Ryan.  If this works for you, mark it checked so others know it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

No javascript needed.  Just use this css:

```
#idOfTheBanner { position:fixed;top:0px;}
```